# Google Documents: Is it possible to replace a shared file?

Tags: google-docs, stata

I would like to have students send me some Stata (`.do`) code by sharing it with me on Google Docs.

**Is it possible to replace the shared with an updated version?**

I don't see any option to do that in the File menu, just renaming and editing the file description.

[image]

Google Docs works well to share and correct papers, but I'm finding it difficult to share and correct anything else. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload multiple versions of the same file.  All the versions will be available for review later.  To upload a new version, Just click on manage revisions (from where you are in your image) and a dialog will appear.   Click on "upload new revision" and navigate to your updated file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see such an option in the "Manage revisions" dialog: http://i.imgur.com/YqsPwu8.png -- perhaps it is reserved to other filetypes?

Comment: Okay, that actually worked perfectly after I reinstalled Google Drive. Problem solved: all students can share files and see edits as long as they have a Google account. It's even better than "Manage revisions": I just modify the file on my disk and they get the updates on their end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe gmail now let's you attach/share updated files to email via Google Drive, and it always keeps the most up-to-date version available. So you can simply update your .do file on your desktop, keep the updated version on your Google Drive, and your students should get them.

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/gmail-and-drive-new-way-to-send-files.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am not certain I understand the whole workflow. Does that system require all students to use Google Drive? How do they get the corrected file? I am trying to understand the step-by-step workflow here and don't get it yet.

Comment: Edwin's answer solves my issue, but I believe that your answer actually recommended the same thing. Sorry for not getting it straight! And thank you Emmy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Google Code (http://code.google.com; if you have a gmail account, you also have the Code account, or at least you can transparently create one from the main Google account), and work with your code using the standard code sharing, development and maintenance tools like Mercurial and its various interfaces. I have developed Stata code pretty much professionally, trust me that this is a much better tool than Google Docs (and any other real programmer here on SO would confirm that).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know about Google Code and use GitHub myself (the course I teach actually lives in a repo over there). However, I would prefer a system that does not involves too much tech for the students. I have also thought about Gist to share code but I think Google Docs will offer the appropriate balance to share both papers and code. It's a shame, though, that Google Docs does not offer plain text preview or editing.

Comment: May be they will offer syntax highlighting and code folding some day :). Although in my experience, different Google projects are often badly unrelated and uncoordinated.